# Mean.js not working. Could not connect to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, npm, mean-stack

**SITUATION:**

I downloaded this repository: https://github.com/meanjs/mean

Followed and executed all instructions.

Did `$ npm start`, got the following error:

---

**ERROR:**

> `Could not connect to MongoDB!
>   { MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect`

---

P.S.: I did install Mongodb and checked it was working with `$ mongod`.

---

**EDIT:**

Full error message if I do `$ npm start` :

```
+ Important warning: config.domain is empty. It should be set to the fully qualified domain of the app.
Could not connect to MongoDB!
{ MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/Users/TLL/Desktop/Web Learn/JobBoard/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:313:35)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/Users/TLL/Desktop/Web Learn/JobBoard/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:271:12)
    at Connection.g (events.js:291:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/TLL/Desktop/Web Learn/JobBoard/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:165:49)
    at Socket.g (events.js:291:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1278:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect' }
(node:5283) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect
/usr/local/bin/node[5283]: ../src/debug-agent.cc:149:void node::debugger::Agent::Stop(): Assertion `(err) == (0)' failed.
 1: node::Abort() [/usr/local/bin/node]
 2: node::RunMicrotasks(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 3: node::debugger::Agent::~Agent() [/usr/local/bin/node]
 4: node::debugger::Agent::~Agent() [/usr/local/bin/node]
 5: node::Environment::~Environment() [/usr/local/bin/node]
 6: node::Start(int, char**) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 7: start [/usr/local/bin/node]
[21:34:44] [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Error if I do `$ mongo`:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.1
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2017-01-31T21:41:14.839+0100 W NETWORK  [main] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2017-01-31T21:41:14.840+0100 E QUERY    [main] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:234:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Comment: try `127.0.0.1` instead of localhost

Comment: does it work if you run `mongo` from commandline?

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ No, I just tried. $mongod works, but not $mongo, let me edit the question with the error code for `mongo`

Comment: @Coder1000 `mongod` is the actual instance of mongodb. let it run, then run your app in another terminal.

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ If I do $mongod, then I can't do $npm start, forgive my ignorance: how do I do it ?

Comment: the problem is the way you connect, instead of using `localhost:27017`, use `127.0.0.1:27017`

Comment: @Coder1000 just open two terminals. run `mongod` on one, then `npm start` on the other one.

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ actually pointed it out. did that not work?

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ Lol, that was way easier than I thought.

Comment: glad it helped :) do you want me to post an answer?

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ Go for it :)

Comment: did you install your local mongodb under C drive (not yje default location that mongodb provides)?

Comment: @Karatay I installed it on my Desktop.

Comment: @Coder1000 During the installation, the mongodb asks the location that you have to choose. Make sure that you choose C:\ drive and create a new directory. You can name it as mongodb

Comment: @Karatay We may have used different methods of installation ? I used homebrew.  I was not prompted to choose a location.

Comment: Could be. You can use their UI installation from Mongodb website. Over there, you can choose the location. After that, as @AMIR described below, follow the steps and it should be good to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start the MongoDB instance using `mongod` in the command line and let it run.

Then on another terminal, run `npm start`. MongoDB instance should be run first.

To see the full options you can pass to `mongod` you can check the [documentations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#start-mongod-processes).

Depending on your operating system, you can search to how you can put the MongoDB instance to be run at boot time, so you don't have to run it manually in a separate window.